# Why can a non-const, non-static member be accessed at compile time without an instance of the class?

Tags: c++, templates, static, compile-time

The following compiles fine in VS2017:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
    int bar;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(Foo::bar), int>, "Foo::bar isn't an int");
    return 0;
}
```

Should the access of Foo::bar not enforce at compile time that it's a static member of Foo? I stumbled upon this while trying to force a specific member variable of a template type to be static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no access to the member `Foo::bar` in `decltype(Foo::bar)` specifier: it simply asks the compiler for the type of `Foo`'s member, an information the compiler knows from `bar`'s declaration alone.

This is similar to `sizeof` expression: you can do `sizeof(Foo::bar)` without having an instance of `Foo` available, and the compiler will produce the correct result.